# Alternative solution to license plates question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm studying probability and I tried to think an alternative approach to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675008/how-many-different-7-place-license-plates-are-possible-when-3-of-the-entries-are). The statement is as follows:

*How many different 7-place license plates are possible
when 3 of the entries are letters and 4 are digits? Assume
that repetition of letters and numbers is allowed and that
there is no restriction on where the letters or numbers can
be placed.*

My alternative approach is this: First, I take any 4 digits from 0 to 9, in combinatorial notation that is $10\choose 4$. Then, for each choice of 4 digits, I choose 3 letters from the 26 of the alphabet, that is $26 \choose 3$. So, I would have 7 elements of which 4 are digits and 3 are letters. For each set of this type, I will arrange the 7 elements, I'll have 7! from this step. So, I would have
$$
{{10}\choose{4}}*{26\choose 3}*7!= 2.751.840.000
$$
possible license plates. However, my question is to know where's the mistake in the reasoning since the answer is
$$
{7\choose 3}*(26)^{3}*(10)^{4}=6.151.600.000
$$

Comment: ${10\choose 4}$ involves the four digits being different.  But repetition is allowed as in $0O0OO00$

Comment: When you choose number, you have $10000=10^4$ options, namely $0000,0001,0002,...,9999$, the same for letters.

Comment: Given the conditions you gave, the answer seems to be incorrect. As you pointed out, it should $7!$, instead of 7 choose 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repetition is allowed.  ${10\choose 4}$ picks 4 distinct numbers (no repeats), whereas $(10)^4$ is four of any number (repeats allowed).  Similarly ${26\choose 3}$ is 3 distinct letters whereas $(26)^3$ allows repetition.

${7\choose 3}$ is the number of ways to choose which of the 7 characters are the letters (with the other 4 obviously being the numbers).  It chooses this way because $10^4$ and $26^3$ both imply ordering amongst themselves.  Ie - if you ended up choosing 1123, in this counting that would be distinct from choosing 1213, etc.  7! ways to arrange the letters/numbers would end up overcounting due to this implicit ordering.